# How to automatically generate notification to user when events is added?

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-apps, django-messages

I have developed a website having functionality such as writing,posting ,user profiles, events & activities, offers..etc.I need to add one more functionality and i.e. Automatic push notification to the users about activities & events, offers and discounts (facebook like notification).

What I want to do is to inform users in their profiles, whenever admin/staff add their events & activities and offers or if user are updating profile, then inform the user of that update. I have looked around many applications but I am still very confused about how to do it.

I really need some proper tutorial or guidance on how to go about doing it. I know how to register a notification and send it on proper signal but there is no documentation on how to show these notices in a template, if this can be done.

Comment: You can use javascript or bootstrap to do that

Comment: You need to create a backend batch job that adds the notification for all users. You need to then add a trigger to this batch job whenever the admin / staff add their events / activities.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/